# Populate cell from table 1 from an auto-filled cell of table 2 with conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2010, TAB1 and TAB2 are in the same worksheet.

I want to populate Column D of TAB1 of an auto-filled Column E of TAB2 based on the values on Column C of TAB2.

TAB1 looks like this:

```
COLUMN C   COLUMN D  COLUMN E
1            
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

TAB2 looks like this

```
COLUMN C   COLUMN E (AUTOFILLED FROM COLUMNS F & G)
1           1205 Grandview Ave
1           1207 Grandview Ave
1           1209 Grandview Ave 
1           1211 Grandview Ave   
2           1500 W 1st Ave
2           1502 W 1st Ave 
2           1504 W 1st Ave 
3           1240 Oakland Ave
```

I have either 144 or 288 rows in TAB1 and lesser rows in TAB2.

How do I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you want to put in column D? The result of an address lookup? Can you specify which values should be in column D in your example?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you are looking to do something like this:

[image: Table]

---

I assume that you want to get the identical part of the addresses rather than the whole string, e.g. `Grandview Ave` rather than `1205 Grandview Ave`. Considering the data in your sample, this can be done by simply cutting everything before the first space in the cell value. If there are no spaces, the cell value won't be cut.

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(G3, LEN(G3) - LEN(LEFT(G3, FIND(" ", G3, 1)))), G3)
```

- `FIND(" ", G3, 1)` finds the first space in cell *G3*.
- `LEFT(G3, FIND())` gets everything to the left of the first space.
- `LEN(LEFT())` gets the number of characters before the first space.
- `RIGHT(G3, LEN(G3) - LEN())` gets everything to the right of the first space.
- `IFERROR(RIGHT(), G3)` returns the cell value if no spaces are found.

After getting the string we want to display, it's simply a matter of doing a `VLOOKUP` to find the value with the right index. The cell will be empty if no matches were found.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F:J,5,FALSE),"")
```

- `VLOOKUP(B3,F:J,5,FALSE)` finds the first value in the fifth column of the range *F:J* with the value of the cell *B3* found in the first column.
- `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(),"")` returns an empty string if no matches are found.

Both of the formulas are copyable.

---

**Bonus A** If you don't care about showing the number of the first match, you can simply  use just:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F,G,2,FALSE),"")
```

**Bonus B** If you don't want to create a support column, you can combine the two formulas by replacing every appearance of *G3* in the first formula with the formula found in Bonus A, which results in the following monstrosity:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F:G,2,FALSE),""), LEN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F:G,2,FALSE),"")) - LEN(LEFT(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F:G,2,FALSE),""), FIND(" ", IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F:G,2,FALSE),""), 1)))), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B3,F:G,2,FALSE),""))
```

---

Also note that some countries use `;` instead of `,` in formulas.